# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list Laravel

Tags: php, mysql

I have following function code in my Controller

```
   public function processEdit($inputs) {


        $id = Input::get('id');
         $user = new User($inputs);
        $result = User::where('id', '=', $id)->update(array($user));
     return view ('welcome');
    }
```

after executing this code i am getting following error

```
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list
```

I have not any column in my table , or my inputs. Any help ?

Comment: Check your `$user` array. I thing it have index **0** which is not a column in you table.

Comment: $data= Input::all(); $id = Input::get('id'); $user = new User($data); $result = User::where('id', '=', $id)->update($user); I have done like this but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using php framework `laravel`, just use `$inputs` instead of `array($user)`

```
$result = User::where('id', '=', $id)->update($inputs);
```

Be sure `$inputs` is a array like this

```
$inputs = ["col1"=>"value1","col2"=>"value2"]
```

Get more detail from Docs : https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#updates

Comment: $data= Input::all();
 $id = Input::get('id');
             $user = new User($data);
            $result = User::where('id', '=', $id)->update($user);

I have done like this but not working

Comment: @Learner: don't put `$user` in `update` method, see the example and docs carefully.

Answer (score 1):

hello guys i think it's because you are using 2d array

```
$orderArr=array($order);
```

so your $orderArr is will be some thing like this:

```
$orderArr=array:2 [▼
  2 => "2"
  4 => "4"
])
```

i had this problem because i was using some thing like this in my view

```
<input name="media[{{$media->id}}]"
```

after i changed it to

```
<input name="{{$media->id}}]"
```

my problem vanished